# Can't collect profile names from identical urls using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to log into facebook using `selenium` and then transfer `cookies` to `requests` module so that I can collect the profile name from the two urls using `requests`. The profile name available in the two urls are not dynamic but they do require log in.

My following script can successfully log in but there might be something wrong while transferring `cookies` and that is perhaps the reason the script throws `AttributeError` when hits this line `name = soup.select_one("#fb-timeline-cover-name > a").text`.

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://www.facebook.com/"

links = [
    "https://www.facebook.com/hillsendagain?fref=gm&dti=157300781073597&hc_location=group",
    "https://www.facebook.com/mark.porton.9?fref=gm&dti=157300781073597&hc_location=group"
]

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("password",Keys.RETURN)

driver_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
c = {c['name']:c['value'] for c in driver_cookies}

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'},cookies=c)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("#fb-timeline-cover-name > a").text
    print(name)
driver.quit()
```

***How can I get only the profile name using requests?***

> PS Getting profile names using selenium alone is not I'm after coz I already know how to do that.

Comment: Yes, you don't have all the cookies with your current code because they are not set immediately, but you can get them if you add a small 5 sec delay before you get the dirver cookies dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam for your suggestion. I'll surely bear that in mind.

Comment: I couldn't get the cookies with Firefox, Python3.7, Windows, but it seems it's not a problem for Chrome. Without the delay I only had a `_js_datr` cookie which caused Facebook to return a 'Not found' page. Also, as noted by SIM the page has to be uncommented for this selector to work. Note that the account name is present in 17 other places in the page and it may be easier to get it from the 'title' tag.

Answer (score 1):

Although the content you are interested in are not dynamic, they are commented out. Try the following to achieve that:

```
for link in links:
    content = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'},cookies=c).text
    comment = content.replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("#fb-timeline-cover-name > a").text
    print(name)
```

In my opinion, using session is what you wanna do to make it robust:

```
s = requests.Session()
[s.cookies.set(cookie['name'],cookie['value']) for cookie in driver.get_cookies()]

for link in links:
    content = s.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
    comment = content.replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("#fb-timeline-cover-name > a").text
    print(name)
```